# Avoiding small numerical errors when using IPython

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, ipython

I have been switching from Matlab to IPython.
In IPython, if we multiply 3.1 by 2.1, the following is the result:

```
In [297]:

3.1 * 2.1
Out[297]:
6.510000000000001
```

There is a small round-off error. It is not a big problem, but it is a little bit annoying. I assume that it appeared while converting decimal numbers into binary numbers and vice versa, is it right?

However, in Numpy array, the result is correct:

```
>>> np.array([3.1 * 2.1])
array([ 6.51])
```

In Matlab command line prompt, also the result is correct:

```
>> 3.1 * 2.1

ans =

    6.5100
```

The above round-off error in Python looks annoying. Are there some ways to avoid this error in the python interactive mode or in IPython?

Comment: Generally you should just use libraries if you need floating point precision, but you can just take out the decimal point, do the multiplication, then insert the decimal point into your output. For your example you would do 31*21=651, and since you multiplied both numbers by 10, and 10*10 is 100, it becomes 6.51

Comment: That isn't a round off error.  The `ipython` display is just showing more decimal points than the other two prints.

Comment: @hpaulj I *would* call it round-off error, since 3.1 \* 2.1 really is equal to 6.51 in normal math. You're right in the sense that the difference in appearance between numpy and Python floats is not meaningful, although both suffer from this imprecision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numpy result is no more precise than the pure Python one - the floating point imprecision is just hidden from you because, by default, numpy prints fewer decimal places of the result:

```
In [1]: float(np.array([3.1 * 2.1]))
Out[1]: 6.510000000000001
```

You can control how numpy displays floating point numbers using [`np.set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html). For example, to print 16 decimal places rather than the usual 8:

```
In [2]: np.set_printoptions(precision=16)

In [3]: np.array([3.1 * 2.1])
Out[3]: array([ 6.5100000000000007])
```

In IPython you can also use the [`%precision`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.basic.html#IPython.core.magics.basic.BasicMagics.precision) magic to control the number of decimal places that are displayed when pretty-printing normal Python floats:

```
In [4]: %precision 8
Out[4]: u'%.8f'

In [5]: 3.1 * 2.1
Out[5]: 6.51000000
```

Note that this is purely cosmetic - the value of `3.1 * 2.1` will still be equal to `6.5100000000000006750155990...` rather than `6.51`.

Answer (score 2):

In Octave, a MATLAB clone, I can display those distant decimals:

```
octave:12> printf("%24.20f\n", 3.1*2.1)
     6.51000000000000067502
```

They are also present your `numpy.array`

```
In [6]: np.array([3.1*2.1]).item()
Out[6]: 6.510000000000001
```

even the component terms involve this sort of rounding:

```
octave:13> printf("%24.20f\n", 3.1)
  3.10000000000000008882
octave:14> printf("%24.20f\n", 2.1)
  2.10000000000000008882
```